# Creating a simple GUI using tkinter, and having a small problem

Tags: python, tkinter

One of the buttons i'm trying to create is not appearing correctly in the window. I've been trying to learn OOP, so my understanding of it is very basic right now, apologies in advance.

The "Submit" button isn't appearing properly.

Here's the code so far:

```
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        master.title('Learning Python')
        master.configure(background='black')
        master.geometry('900x200')
        master.resizable(0, 0)


class Submit(Button):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        Button(text='Submit', background='black', foreground='light green', highlightthickness=0,
               border=0)
        Button.pack(self)


class ProgressBar(ttk.Progressbar):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(orient='horizontal')
        progress_bar.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)


class PagesRead(Label):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        pages_label = Label(text='How many page(s) did you read?', background='black', foreground='light green')
        pages_label.pack()


class EntryBox(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        Entry(master)
        Entry.pack(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Window(root)
    bar = ProgressBar(root)
    pages = PagesRead(root)
    entry = EntryBox(root)
    submit = Submit(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you deriving your own widgets from the one provided by `tkinter`? There doesn't appear to be any additional functionality being added.

Comment: _"The "Submit" button isn't appearing properly."_ - what does that mean? How is it appearing, and how is that different from what you expect?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to learn OOP, you're learning bad habits with this code.

Let's take a look at this code:

```
class Submit(Button):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        Button(text='Submit', background='black', foreground='light green', highlightthickness=0,
               border=0)
        Button.pack(self)
```

First, because you inherit from `Button`, this class *is a* `Button`. You then call `Button(text=...)` which creates *another* button, so now you have two. If you're going to inherit from some other class, you don't need to create a second instance of that same class.

Also, these two lines are wrong:

```
super().__init__()
self.master = master
```

You need to pass `master` to the `__init__` of the superclass. The master is more than just an attribute, it's an integral part of the definition of the widget. It affects how the widget will appear. It *must* be passed to the superclass in order for the widget to be properly initialized.

Also, this is slightly more subjective, but you should not be calling `Button.pack(self)` from within the definition of `Submit`. One of the main reasons for objects is to make reusable components. By having a widget call `pack` (or `grid` or `place`) on itself severely limits its re-usability. By calling `pack` inside `Submit`, it prevents you from using it or moving it to some other location in your UI which uses `grid`. That is an unnecessary constraint.

In my experience, the overall layout of a UI will change during development. What if you decide that you want to switch from `pack` to `grid` because you've designed to change the layout?  The way you have written this code, you will have to modify every single class.

Instead, code that creates a widget should be responsible for calling `pack`, `grid`, or `place`. That means moving the call outside of the class and into the code that instantiates the class. This way, if you choose to use `grid`, or stay with `pack` but use some extra frames for organization, you only have to change the one function that creates each widget, rather than having to change every widget itself.

For example, the `Submit` button class should more look like this:

```
class Submit(Button):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.configure(text='Submit', background='black', foreground='light green',
                       highlightthickness=0, border=0)
```

Then, in the same code where it's created, that's where you call pack

```
submit = Submit(root)
...
submit.pack(...)
```

If you later decide to switch to `grid`, all you have to change is that last block of code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's just a single thing that's preventing the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button from being displayed, nor why you're deriving specialized widget subclasses that do nothing but hardcode some option settings into themselves — but, in general, you're not doing it correctly especially with respect to calling the superclass `__init__()` and configuring the instance inside each derived class' own `__init__()`.

The reason this is a less than ideal way of doing things is because it's going to require different subclasses for every, say `Button` widget, your application needs — when all that's really required are instances of a single `Button` class with different values assigned to its attributes (which `tkinter` calls "options").

Subclassing should only be used when the actual *code* needs to be different. See the **Definitions of subclass** section of [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)#Definitions_of_subclass) on ***Classes***.

So, in my opinion you should instead just create instance of the stock `tkinter` widget and assign the options you want each to have when you create the instances. This is the way it's usually done and would be a lot simpler.

Anyway, here's how to do implement your approach correctly, which also happens to fix the `Button` not displaying issue:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        master.title('Learning Python')
        master.config(background='black')
        master.geometry('900x200')
        master.resizable(0, 0)


class Submit(Button):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.config(text='Submit', background='black', foreground='light green',
                    highlightthickness=0, border=0)
        self.pack()


class ProgressBar(ttk.Progressbar):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.config(orient='horizontal')
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)


class PagesRead(Label):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.config(text='How many page(s) did you read?', background='black',
                    foreground='light green')
        self.pack()


class EntryBox(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Window(root)
    bar = ProgressBar(root)
    pages = PagesRead(root)
    entry = EntryBox(root)
    submit = Submit(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Screenshot

[image: screenshot of tkinter app running and displaying all widgets]