# Increasing the ProgressBar in tkinter by x amount entered

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm having problem with a function that I'm working on. The goal i'm trying to achieve is that, when a number is:

I have a Progress Bar, with the max limit being 1462.
Whenever a number is entered into the window, and the **Submit** button is pressed, I just simply want the Progress Bar to increase by how much was entered into the window.

I'm getting an error on my increase_progress function, and not being able to achieve the desired result.

Relevant code:

```
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        master.title('Learning Python')
        master.configure(background='black')
        master.geometry('900x200')
        master.resizable(0, 0)


class Submit(Button):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.configure(text='Submit', background='black', foreground='light green', highlightthickness=0,
                       border=0)


class Clear(Button):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.configure(text='Clear', background='black', foreground='light green', highlightthickness=0,
                       border=0)


class ProgressBar(ttk.Progressbar):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.config(orient='horizontal', maximum=1462, mode='determinate')



class PagesRead(Label):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.config(text='How many page(s) did you read?', background='black', foreground='light green')


class EntryBox(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)


def increase_progress():
    progress = int(entry.get())
    if progress:
        ProgressBar.step(progress)


root = tk.Tk()
app = Window(root)

bar = ProgressBar(root)
bar.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

pages = PagesRead(root)
pages.pack()

entry = EntryBox(root)
entry.pack()


submit = Submit(root)
submit.pack()

clear = Clear(root)
clear.config(command=lambda: entry.delete(0, 'end'))
clear.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error.

Comment: I see you're still creating widget subclasses like in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58963536/creating-a-simple-gui-using-tkinter-and-having-a-small-problem), which both Bryan and I mentioned wasn't a very good way to do OOP..

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class Window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        master.title('Learning Python')
        master.configure(background='black')
        master.geometry('900x200')
        master.resizable(0, 0)


class Submit(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.configure(text='Submit', background='black', foreground='light green', highlightthickness=0,
                       border=0, command=increase_progress)


class Clear(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.configure(text='Clear', background='black', foreground='light green', highlightthickness=0,
                       border=0)


class ProgressBar(ttk.Progressbar):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.config(orient='horizontal', maximum=1462, mode='determinate')


class PagesRead(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.config(text='How many page(s) did you read?', background='black', foreground='light green')


class EntryBox(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)


def increase_progress():
    progress = int(entry.get())
    if progress:
        bar['value'] += progress


root = tk.Tk()
app = Window(root)

bar = ProgressBar(root)
bar.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

pages = PagesRead(root)
pages.pack()

entry = EntryBox(root)
entry.pack()


submit = Submit(root)
submit.pack()

clear = Clear(root)
clear.config(command=lambda: entry.delete(0, 'end'))
clear.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Your problem was that you haven't used the value method in progressbar. This code works :) check it out